# Generating functions in combinatorics topic: Pascal triangle for bivariate function

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algorithms, generating-functions, arithmetic-combinatorics

> Let $\displaystyle \left[\frac{n}{k}\right]$ a combinatorial element meaning the number of permutations with exactly $k$ increasing sequences. Find a Pascal Triangle type recurence formula for the combinatorial element. *Source: Theoretical Algorithmics and Mathematical Computer Science European Contest (TAMCSEC) 2011*

**Background and motivation:**

I have found this problem related to the topic Generating Functions in a textbook in Combinatorics. Even though I have some (but not very advanced) training in this topic, especially in the theoretical field (definitions, relations, properties of both $\text{ordgen}$ and $\text{expgen}$, with formulae for manipulating different sequences, as well as knowledge of Differential Calculus topics needed here - series expansions especially). However, **I did not encouner any problem of this type so far related to generating functions. I am searching for a solution related with the topic of generating function, as well as some explanations connecting this theoretical topic with combinatorics.**

*Edit:* I am also familiar with normal combinatorial elements (binomials and multinomials, arrangements, including Pascal recursivity) and with some info about permutations and there properties in combinatorics and probability.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you mean by "$k$ increasing sequences"? Must they be consecutive, or not? For example, does $\pi=[1,2,5,6,3,4,7,8]$ have exactly $2$ increasing sequences (namely $1,2,3,4$ and $5,6,7,8$), or does it have $4$ increasing sequences (namely $[1,2]$, $[5,6]$, $[3,4]$ and $[7,8]$)?

Comment: @MikeEarnest Consecutive blocks

Comment: Exactly $k$ increasing runs means exactly $k-1$ descents, and vice versa. So, check [Eulerian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### $\displaystyle
\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]=(n-k+1)\left[\frac{n-1}{k-1}\right]+k\left[\frac{n-1}{k}\right]$ for $1\le k\le n$

$\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]$ is the same as [the Eulerian number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) $A(n, k-1)$, as [Alexander Burstein](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4405000/generating-functions-in-combinatorics-topic-pascal-triangle-for-bivariate-funct#comment9216914_4405000) points out.
While $\left[\frac n0\right]=\left[\frac {n-1}{n}\right]=0$ if $n\gt0$ by definition, we stipulate $\left[\frac00\right]=1$.

Since $$A(n,m) = (n-m)A(n-1,m-1)+(m+1)A(n-1,m)$$ for $1\le m\le n-1$ as mentioned in the Wikipedia article, we have, for $2\le k\le n$,
$$ \begin{aligned}
\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]&=A(n,k-1)\\
&=(n-k+1)A(n-1,k-2)+kA(n-1,k-1)\\
&=(n-k+1)\left[\frac{n-1}{k-1}\right]+k\left[\frac{n-1}{k}\right]
\end{aligned}$$
This is the wanted "Pascal Triangle type recurrence formula".

##### A simple direct proof

Given a sequence, let us call a consecutive increasing subsequence that cannot be extended to a longer consecutive increasing subsequence a **block** of the given sequence. $\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]$ is the number of permutations of $(1,2,\cdots,n)$ with $k$ blocks.

Note that every permutation of $(1,2,\cdots, n)$ can be obtain from a permutation of $(1,2,\cdots, n-1)$ by inserting $n$ somewhere.

- If $n$ is inserted right after the end of a block, the number of blocks will not change.
- Otherwise, $n$ is inserted elsewhere, i.e.,

  - inside some block, in which case that block will split into two blocks;
  - or at the very front of the whole permutation, in which case $n$ itself forms a new block.

  The number of blocks will increase by $1$.

So, to obtain permutations of $1,2,\cdots,n$ with $k$ blocks, we can

- either insert $n$ right after the end of one of $k$ blocks of a permutation of $1,2\cdots,n-1$ with $k$ blocks,
- or insert $n$ at one of all $n$ positions except right after the end of one of $k-1$ blocks of a permutation of $1,2,\cdots, n-1$ with $k-1$ blocks.

Combining the two cases above, we obtain
$$\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]=k\left[\frac{n-1}{k}\right]+(n-(k-1))\left[\frac{n-1}{k-1}\right]\quad \forall 1\le k\le n.$$